# Breeze.js generate metadata for pocos

Tags: breeze

I am trying to find a way to generate breeze metadata from poco's. It seem that hand writing js models is error prone and duplicates work. I cant put everything I have in EF. Some of the data I have is coming from a 3ed party web service. I would think there should me a function for this.
What is the correct way to do what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good question, and we've discussed creating a reflection metadata provider but haven't gotten further than that.  Please add this to the [Breeze User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions).  We take these suggestions very seriously.

Another, slightly hacky, approach is that you can use EF's CodeFirst annotations on your model without actually using EF for anything other than metadata creation. In fact, you only need to run the EF metadata creation logic once and cache this on the server in a file, so that you never need EF at runtime at all.  The CodeFirst annotations are also not very intrusive and if Breeze were to implement a reflection provider, we would probably need to create similar annotations.